# how to get frame of 'screen viewport' in zoomed uiview?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiimageview

I have a UIImageView which can be zoomed and panned via gesture controls.  (I am not using an UIScrollView for this, for no reason other than that I was building from a tutorial and didn't learn about Scroll Views until later.)

I want to add another view as a subview of the main Image View, and I want the frame of the new view to be the region shown on the screen.   i.e. if the main image is zoomed in to very fine detail so that only a tiny piece of the image is showing, then I want the frame of the new view to be only that visible piece.

Similarly, if the main view is zoomed way out, so that it appears very small on the screen, I want the frame of the new view to be comparatively very large, encompassing everything shown on the screen.

Would prefer an answer in terms of Swift language, but I can convert from Objective C.

In case it's relevant: The ultimate application for all this is for hand-gesture drawing, so that I'm allocating the appropriate amount of space & resources for the region the user is likely to try & draw.  It'd be memory-wasteful to make the frame of the new "UIBezierCurveView" be the frame of the entire (hi res) image if they're zoomed way in.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to have some sort of overlay that is laid over the entire, pan-able area.

You can just add a UIView above the UIImageView. In this fashion:

```
-Superview
    -UIView (call this OverlayView)
        -Anything you want on that UIView
    -(pan-able)UIImageView
```

And then you just make sure that the UIView doesn't respond to touch events and they are passed down below to the UIImageView using (sorry for the Obj-C although it's very simple):

```
//set it to false to let touches go through
OverlayView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

Comment: I don't see how that will give me the currently viewable area.   Unless, there's something like  `newFrame = CGRectInView( OverlayView.frame, imageView)`?

Comment: Then I think I missed what you were trying to do. It's a bit hard to visualize from your explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.  Posting this answer for anyone who comes along in the future.  The solution is one line:

```
let frame = imageView.convertRect(rootView.bounds, fromView: rootView)
```

...where imageView is the UIImageView in question, and rootView is the UIView that is supplied by default in Storyboard which contains the UIImageView.  (No new overlay need be introduced and userInteractionEnabled is irrelevant.)

NOTE: Even if you connect rootView as an @IBObject from Storyboard into ViewController.swift, it will NOT be allocated and will return nil.
You must also connect rootView with the UIImageView and select one of the options regarding how it should act as a container to the UIImageView (I 
think I chose center horizontally). Only then will rootView be usable.